# Google-chrome source code download stuck at 97%

Tags: google-chrome

I was following http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code#TOC-Update-to-the-latest-revision and trying to download the chrome source. The `gclient sync` command got stuck at 97% for the last 24 hours. Any idea on whats going wrong and how to resolve this?

```
66>_____ src/tools/page_cycler/acid3 at 633fc66cc99ae5bb92b567c6beafde7a01cfdb49
51>_____ src/third_party/smhasher/src at b35e562e2d80bc47a51b53ec92a305eb9a3383b4
67>_____ src/v8 at efdb9d70bddd496ceb6a281dadcc065efbce37a1
59>_____ src/third_party/webgl_conformance at ca8d511e3fa5808f8a43bf92a5a6130ce77f78de
49>_____ src/third_party/skia/src at 7c3dd08d4637dac8fff05baec2c330c9557bf932
61>_____ src/third_party/xdg-utils at 7b903508c0dea743114236c35866a9131121ba61
65>_____ src/tools/gyp at 891e8aba7606c57610ce512d6c8c93321b79a715
syncing projects:  97% (66/68) src/tools/gyp
```

Comment: What happens when you cancel and restart?

Comment: Does simply killing existing process (with `Ctrl-C` in bash) and starting it again works? I'm not familiar with gclient, but most of VCSs can easily resume synchronization...

Comment: Canceling and restarting ends up in the same state!